# How to check if frame source has changed and open source in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, frame

We are creating a web-based mobile app.  The app has an ad that loads in a narrow frame.  In testing on the iPhone, we noticed that when the ad is clicked, it loads within the ad frame (of the native app), instead of opening in a new window.

We are now looking to detect whether an ad has been clicked by checking the source of the frame.  If the source has changed, we would like to grab that URL and open it in a new window using Javascript.  Then, we would like to reset the source of the frame to the original.

Here is the code we have so far.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout( checkAdLocation, 250 );
});

function checkAdLocation() {
    var adLocation = window.frames['adframe'].document.location;
    if(adLocation!='http://path/play.php?showad') {
        window.frames['adframe'].document.location.href = 'play.php?showad';
        window.open( adLocation );
    }
    alert( adLocation);
    setTimeout( checkAdLocation, 2000 );
}

</script>

<frameset cols='50%,50%'>
   <frame src='play.php?showad' name=adframe>
   <frame src='http://google.com'>
</frameset>
```

Thanks.

Comment: does appending `&lt1=_new` to the `src` of iframe solve the problem

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but I'm using frames, not iframes.

Just tried and it didn't do anything.  I'm looking to create a new window only when something inside the frame is clicked.

Comment: o0ps! sorry i hurriedly read it and commented...

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like the ad lives on the same domain? If that is the case, it's probably easiest to just inject a `target="_blank"` to all a tags in that frame.

Using jQuery (which you included in your example so I'm assuming that is okay to use), this should do it:

```
    $(adframe.document.body).find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: The ad actually doesn't live on the same domain and the ad code is also generated via javascript.  For testing purposes, what I have in "play.php?showad" is just a javascript include to a .js file.  Inside the js file, it only has one line of code: document.write("<a href=http://google.com>google.com</a>");  In other words, inside the HTML of "play.php?showad" itself, there is no <a> tag.